# Module variable as output of a method

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript module:

```
const myModule = {
  foo: this.initializeFoo(),

  initializeFoo(){
    // some loops and stuff to create an array
  }
}
```

But I get an error: `this.initializeFoo` is not a function.

Is there some syntax I need to use to make this work, or is it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only intend to call it once and at the object's creation, then I would opt for a self-executing anonymous function:

```
const myModule = {
    foo: (function () {
        // some loops and stuff to create an array
    })()
};
```

Alternatively, you can use arrow syntax instead:

```
const myModule = {
    foo: (() => {
        // some loops and stuff to create an array
    })()
}
```

Example snippet:

```js
const myModule = {
    foo: (() => {
        console.log('Processing');
        return Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(Number.call, Number);
    })()
};

// You can see that 'Processing' is only printed once
console.log(myModule.foo[2]);
console.log(myModule.foo[7]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `initializeFoo()` function in outside of the Object

```js
const myModule = {
      foo : initializeFoo(),
    }
     
     function initializeFoo(){
     return 'hi';
     //or some loops and stuff to create an array
     }
    
    console.log(myModule)
```

Comment: I want the function to only run once on load, and save the output to a variable that I can access many times

Comment: You could then make it an immediately invoked function that returns a constant if it only needs to run ocne and them keep the same value.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6:

```
class MyModule {
  constructor() {
    this.initializeFoo();
  }
  initializeFoo() {
    console.log('test');
    // some loops and stuff to create an array
  }
}

const myModule = new MyModule();
```

If you need to store the result of `initializeFoo()`:

```
class MyModule {
  constructor() {
    this.initializeFoo();
  }
  initializeFoo(){
    console.log('test');
    this.initialVal = 2;
  }
}

const myModule = new MyModule();
// 'test'

myModule.initialVal
// 2
```